# Referencing an external link from DITA map

Tags: excel, dita

Is there any way to reference an external document from DITA?
According to some guidelines it should be easy via `(within <map>) <keydef> keys=keyID` and `(within <task>) <link>keyref=keyID`,
but the validator simply does not accept it.

I intend to reference an xlsx-sheet:

```
<title>SpringerMaterials Content Enrichment - Annotation Guide - V01.00</title>
<keydef keys="protocolFile" href="examples/VIII6A3_CV_prototype.xlsx" format="xlsx" scope="external"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keydef you show is in a map then it looks correct.

Within a topic you can use  to point to the key:

```
<p>See <xref keyref="protocolFile">Sample Protocol Data</xref>...
```

What validation message are you getting?

Comment: Unfortunately the validation says:
The XML parser reported the following error:  : <maptitle>.ditamap Line 42: The content of element type "map" must match "(title?, topicmeta?, (anchor|data-about| <etc.>). 

Thus <keydef> does not seem to be allowed within a map, which surprises me.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems your map is not valid. Hopefully this example helps you.

**myMap.ditamap**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">
<map>
 <title>Title of Your Map</title>

  <!-- Reference to the Topic -->
  <topicref keys="myTopic"/>

  <!-- Your Keymap -->
  <mapref href="myKeymap.ditamap" format="ditamap"/>
</map>
```

**myKeymap.ditamap**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">
<map>
 <title>My Keymap</title>

  <keydef keys="myTopic" href="myTopic.dita"/>
  <keydef keys="myFile" href="myFile.xlsx" navtitle="myFile" scope="external" format="xlsx"/>
</map>
```

**myTopic.dita**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="myTopic">
  <title>myTopic</title>
  <body>
    <p>This is a link to myFile.xlsx: <xref keyref="myFile"/>.</p>
  </body>
</topic>
```